# How can I get a high level view of all my organization's running github actions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Like many of you, we've switched from our own Jenkins CI to Github Actions.

In Jenkins, you see all of the running jobs, but in Github Actions you have to go to each repository and view their Actions. This is less than ideal for my workflow.

Is there a way to get a higher level view of all running actions for my organization, or is everything really so partitioned at the repository level?

I know about /settings/actions/runners but I still have to open each active runner to see which actions are running.

I really want to be able to see all of the actions that are running in a single page.

This is what I see in settings/actions/runners [image]

Note that I can only see whether a job is running or not for a runner. I want to be able to see all jobs runnings in my organization just like I could for Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to view all the active jobs across all runners in one place.

There is a possibility to view only the info about active jobs **per runner**.

By default, each organization has a pre-installed GitHub-hosted runner managed by GitHub. You can also add your own [self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners).

**To view the active GH Actions jobs in the organization:**

- Open your organization page
- Click *Settings*
- Navigate to *Actions* section on the left menu
- Click *Runners* menu item
- Select the *GitHub-hosted runners* (or your own runner in case you have a self-hosted runner)

As a result, you should see the following page:

[image]

The Active jobs section will display all of the jobs that are currently running across all of the organization's repositories.

For more details, see the [Monitoring your current jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/monitoring-your-current-jobs)

Comment: "I know about /settings/actions/runners but I still have to open each active runner to see which actions are running."

Comment: @Novaterata anyway, it shows active jobs across all the repositories for a runner. It's the only possible way.

Comment: Yes, and I don't see why that would be weird. This is really basic stuff for a CI system to do, if you want to change your answer to "No, you can't" I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Novaterata agree with you. Maybe, GitHub will consider adding such a feature in the future. Updated a bit the answer.